First time printing PETG; how can I improve the quality?
This is the first time I have tried to print PETG and this is what I got. Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this problem? I used Qidi slicer with a nozzle temperature of 240 °C for the first layer and other layers at 250 °C with the bed at 80 °C all the time. I am new to 3D printing so I use simple mode to begin with.


Can you add a link or an image of the STL model? It is pretty hard to know what is wrong while we don't know what it supposed to look like. It appears as if you're trying to print an overhang, but it is difficult to see based on your printed object image. Maybe you could also add why you need this to be printed in PETG.

It's nearly a standard answer for PETG work to ensure that your filament has been dried in a filament dryer or equivalent. Even fresh-in-the-package filament will have absorbed moisture resulting in terrible prints. That would be the first step to engage.

I use 250 all layer and for bed start at 70 and go to 60 on textured PEI,
but most important keep it at list under 40% humidity better if your have very little fan speed

Presumably you mean °C? A number without a unit is meaningless.

It is also important for PETG that there is no air draft. As long as I didn't close the printer, the prints were blooming for me too. I made a closure of MDF and the doors of transparent acryl. Of course, I printed the brackets (corners) and hinges.
